# jQuery Validate : container and HTML validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, wrapper

I'm using jQuery validate, with the container fonctionnality: all errors are shown in a ul>li structure, at the top of the page.

It is working well, but the generated code is not valid HTML. Here is the initial HTML:

```
<div id="error-container">
    <ul/>
</div>
```

And my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container = $("#error-container ul");
    $(".validate").validate({
        ignoreTitle: true,
        errorLabelContainer: container,
        wrapper: "li",
        meta: "validate",
    });
});
//-->
</script>
```

The problem is that the  tag is not valid. I tried to overload some methods of jQuery validate to add this ul wrapper automatically when errors are displayed, but it's so hard to read that I failed.

Do you see any solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup to this -

```
<div id="error-container">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is also not valid, because UL is still empty.

Comment: For what reason do you need the HTML to validate?

Comment: Because it is a good practice to always have HTML valid, and because it is semantically a nonsense to have an empty list in the DOM.

Comment: But you may be throwing the baby out with the bathwater. We all strive for good clean semantic code that validates, but since you're populating the list via Ajax you may want to give up notions of having the initial HTML validate and only validate after everything has been loaded into the DOM.

Comment: You could always include an empty list item and hide the empty with jquery. Or you could read this by one of SO's leaders - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/html-validation-does-it-matter.html

Comment: Empty list item is the same or worse... My list is not populated when the page loads, only after form validation. Thus, I want a solution in which the HTML is valid at page load (meaning without an empty list or list item), and after form validation (meaning with a list populated by jQuery Validate)